# Formula is too long and taking a lot of time to calculate

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet like that but with more than 4k rows:

```
DATA SPREADSHEET
   A           B         C      D       E       F       G         H
Job Num    Part Num    Start    OP     Req    Issue    OHQ      Check
 12344       ABCC       4/11   ASEMB   60       60      0      Issued
 12344       ABCC       4/11   ASEMB   60       60     20      Issued
 12344       ABCC       4/13   ASEMB   60       60     14      Issued
 12345       ABCD       4/11   ASEMB           
 12346       ABCE       4/28   ASEMB           
 12347       ABCF       4/11   ASEMB   72       0     23131   OK to Issue
 12347       ABCF       4/11   ASEMB    2       0       0     Not Enough
 12348       ABCG       6/03   ASEMB   764      0     5398    OK to Issue
 12348       ABCG       5/31   ASEMB   600      0     2039    OK to Issue
 12349       ABCG       5/31   ASEMB   100      0      218    OK to Issue
 12349       ABCG       5/31   ASEMB   200      0       0     Not Enough
 12340       ABCG       4/18   ASEMB   600      0     2039    OK to Issue
 12340       ABCG       4/18   ASEMB   100      0      218    OK to Issue
 12340       ABCG       4/18   ASEMB   200      0       0     Not Enough
```

The H column is generated with the formula: =IF(F2="", "",IF(F2>=E2, "Issued", IF(G2>E2, "OK to Issue", "Not Enough")))

With this sheet, I created a Summary Sheet that copies the columns A, B, C, and D and checks for duplicates. After the duplicates are removed, I create a formula for the column E and the sheet looks like this:

```
SUMMARY SPREADSHEET
   A           B         C      D         E
Job Num    Part Num    Start    OP      Check
 12344       ABCC       4/11   ASEMB    Issued
 12344       ABCC       4/13   ASEMB    Issued
 12345       ABCD       4/11   ASEMB           
 12346       ABCE       4/28   ASEMB
 12347       ABCF       4/11   ASEMB   Not Enough
 12348       ABCG       6/03   ASEMB   OK to Issue
 12348       ABCG       5/31   ASEMB   OK to Issue
 12349       ABCG       5/31   ASEMB   Not Enough
 12340       ABCG       4/18   ASEMB   Not Enough
```

To generate column E, I came up with the following enormous formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A2)*(Sheet1!C:C=Sheet2!C2)*(Sheet1!D:D=Sheet2!D2)*(Sheet1!H:H="Not Enough"))>0,"Not Enough",IF(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A2)*(Sheet1!C:C=Sheet2!C2)*(Sheet1!D:D=Sheet!D2)*(Sheet1!H:H="OK to Issue"))>0, "OK to Issue",IF(SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A2)*(Sheet1!C:C=Sheet2!C2)*(Sheet1!D:D=Sheet2!D2)*(Sheet1!H:H="Issued"))>0,"Issued", "")))
```

My problem is with the formula that generates column E, it's too long and it's taking forever to calculate, especially because this spreadsheet has a little over 3k rows. Is there a way that I can have this same result but with another formula?

To clarify, what I need to do is:

I need to compare the Summary Spreadsheet with the Data Spreadsheet. Since the summary is smaller because I eliminated the duplicates, I need the column E for the Summary Spreadsheet to check if:
Job Num + Part Num + Start = Check

Sometimes I have Job Num that has a different Start or OP value, and this is shown in the Summary Data. After I delete the duplicates, I still have a Job Num like the 12348 that is there twice because it has a different Start Date.

So, for each Job Num + Start + OP in the Summary Spreadsheet, I need to check if the Data Spreadsheet is "Not Enough", "OK to Issue", "", or "Issued". For the Check column in the Summary Spreadsheet, I have the following order:

1. If "Not Enough" > 0, then "Not Enough". If not:
2. If "OK to Issue" > 0, then "OK to Issue". If not:
3. If "" > 0, then "". If not:
4. If none of those, then "Issued"

For example, if you take a look at the Data Spreadsheet, I have 3 entries for the Job Num 12340, and the Start Date and OP are also the same, but for the Check column, I have 2 Entries that are "OK to Issue", but one that is "Not Enough". So for the Summary Spreadsheet, I just need one entry for the Job Num 12340 and the Check column needs to be "Not Enough", following the 4 orders above.

If it makes it easier, the Part Num can also be checked with the Job Num, Start, and OP in the Summary Spreadsheet (when compared with the Data Spreadsheet).

I tried to explain what I need to be done in the best way I could. Let me know if it's understandable.
If anyone has a better idea of how to solve this, please help me. I am about to go crazy with this task.

Comment: Don't use full column References.  Even limiting it to 10,000 rows will make a huge improvement.  Either dynamically find the last row or use a table structure to help limit the formula to only the data that exists.

Comment: Use helper columns to resolve some of the testing and copy paste.special values to keep a binary result.

Comment: If a result will never change, copy the column and paste the result.

Comment: Also, why `SUMPRODUCT` for this?  `COUNTIFS` will do the job and should calculate much faster.